# How to make sheet name as a variable

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub WriteToZeroBasedArray()
    
    Dim V() As Variant ' Note the parentheses!
    Dim P() As Variant
    Dim N() As Variant
    Dim Index As Long
    Dim Index_2 As Long
    Dim Index_3 As Long
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = Worksheets("0618").Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column ' e.g.
    
    Dim c As Long
    For c = 7 To cCount
        If 0 < Worksheets("0618").Cells(9, c).Value And Worksheets("0618").Cells(9, c).Value < 100 Then
            ReDim Preserve V(Index)
            ' A safer way (Option Base related):
            'ReDim Preserve V(0 To Index)
            V(Index) = Worksheets("0618").Cells(2, c).Value
            Index = Index + 1
            
            ReDim Preserve P(Index_2)
            P(Index_2) = Worksheets("0618").Cells(4, c).Value
            Index_2 = Index_2 + 1
            
            ReDim Preserve N(Index_3)
            N(Index_3) = Worksheets("0618").Cells(9, c).Value
            Index_3 = Index_3 + 1
        End If
    Next c
    
     
    Dim K As Integer
    Dim L As Integer
    
    K = UBound(V)
    For L = 0 To K
      If L < 5 Then
        Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(L + 6, 1).Value = V(L)
        Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(L + 6, 2).Value = P(L)
        Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(L + 6, 3).Value = N(L)
      Else
        Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(M + 1, 5).Value = V(L)
        Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(M + 1, 6).Value = P(L)
        Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(M + 1, 7).Value = N(L)
      End If
      
    Next
    
    If Index = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    Debug.Print Join(V, vbLf)
    
    

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub WriteToZeroBasedArray()
    
    Dim SheetName As String
    SheetName = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(3, 10).Value
    Dim V() As Variant ' Note the parentheses!
    Dim P() As Variant
    Dim N() As Variant
    Dim Index As Long
    Dim Index_2 As Long
    Dim Index_3 As Long
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = Worksheets("SheetName").Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column ' e.g.
    
    Dim c As Long
    For c = 7 To cCount
        If 0 < Worksheets("0618").Cells(9, c).Value And Worksheets("SheetName").Cells(9, c).Value < 100 Then
            ReDim Preserve V(Index)
            ' A safer way (Option Base related):
            'ReDim Preserve V(0 To Index)
            V(Index) = Worksheets("SheetName").Cells(2, c).Value
            Index = Index + 1
            
            ReDim Preserve P(Index_2)
            P(Index_2) = Worksheets("SheetName").Cells(4, c).Value
            Index_2 = Index_2 + 1
            
            ReDim Preserve N(Index_3)
            N(Index_3) = Worksheets("SheetName").Cells(9, c).Value
            Index_3 = Index_3 + 1
        End If
    Next c
    
     
    Dim K As Integer
    Dim L As Integer
    
    K = UBound(V)
    For L = 0 To K
      If L < 5 Then
        Worksheets("sheet3").Cells(L + 6, 1).Value = V(L)
        Worksheets("sheet3").Cells(L + 6, 2).Value = P(L)
        Worksheets("sheet3").Cells(L + 6, 3).Value = N(L)
      Else
        Worksheets("sheet3").Cells(M + 1, 5).Value = V(L)
        Worksheets("sheet3").Cells(M + 1, 6).Value = P(L)
        Worksheets("sheet3").Cells(M + 1, 7).Value = N(L)
      End If
      
    Next
    
    If Index = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    Debug.Print Join(V, vbLf)
    
    

End Sub
```

I changed 'sheet3' of the first code to SheetName variable in second one, because I wanted to apply this code to any sheets that the user wants. But when I run the code, the Msgbox says
'''
: cCount = Worksheets("SheetName").Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column
'''
this part has something wrong.
Could someone please help me?

Comment: Remove the double quotes around your variable otherwise it will be treated as a string literal. `cCount = Worksheets(SheetName).Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column`

Comment: Yes, SheetName is a string variable. no quotes required.

Comment: I got it! Thank you!